# The Windows application cannot be built although it's the code is from Microsoft

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I'm new to making Windows applications. I follow [Microsoft's tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program).

When I build the application, an error occurs. It says:

> undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

I don't know how to solve this question. [The tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program)'s code also cannot build successfully.

The environment:

Windows version: Windows 10 21H2

C++ language standard: C++ 20

windows.h: from g++

IDE: CLion 2020.3

Comment: Can you post your code please ?

Comment: Add defines for `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` to the project settings.  The project is being build as non-Unicode but `wWinMain` is the Unicode entry point. Looking at the tutorial it requires a Unicode project.  If you are leaning MS-Windows and C++ I suggest you use Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community edition - as there will be less changes from tutorials.